# Chromebook not displaying battery life

Tags: google-chrome-os

Sometimes my Chromebook (running ChromeOS 80.0.3987.158 Official Build) doesn't display the wifi and battery life details in the bottom right. This appears to be after opening certain apps that go full screen. Example:

[image]

Clicking on GB, unsurprisingly, doesn't give me the dialogues for the wifi/battery/etc either:
[image]

The only way I have found to fix this is log off and log on, which is less than ideal and harder to do when you can't select the option in the bottom right.

Anyone know how to get the icons back?